# Fluentd parser for OpenWRT logs

Tags: regex, logging, fluentd, openwrt, rsyslog

Now I'm working on collecting logs from many OenWRT routers and using for this task fluentd.

Unfortunately, I don't know why my parser isn't working.

For example, logs looks like this:

```
Aug 15 06:55:05 HOST123 daemon:warning Expiring: (mcpd_process_query_timer)
Aug 15 06:55:05 HOST123 daemon:warning Sending IGMPv2 query of len: 8
Aug 15 06:55:05 HOST123 daemon:warning MLD QUERY: MRT is 00:0a ifindex=15
Aug 15 06:55:05 HOST123 daemon:warning Sending Query size: 28
Aug 15 06:55:07 HOST123 daemon:notice iptv (8359): udhcpc: sending renew to 192.168.131.1
Aug 15 06:55:21 HOST123 daemon:notice data (8351): udhcpc: sending renew to 192.168.130.1
Aug 15 07:06:17 HOST123 daemon:notice voice (6262): udhcpc: sending renew to 192.168.117.1
Aug 15 07:06:17 HOST123 daemon:notice voice (6262): udhcpc: lease of 192.168.117.8 obtained, lease time 600
Aug 15 07:06:22 HOST123 daemon:notice mgmt (6263): udhcpc: sending renew to 192.168.121.1
Aug 15 07:06:22 HOST123 daemon:notice mgmt (6263): udhcpc: lease of 192.168.121.8 obtained, lease time 600
Aug 15 07:06:24 HOST123 daemon:notice iptv (6261): udhcpc: sending renew to 192.168.131.1
Aug 15 07:06:25 HOST123 daemon:notice iptv (6261): udhcpc: lease of 192.168.131.8 obtained, lease time 600
```

My config:

```
<source>
  @type syslog
  port 1514
  tag  scom
  <parse>
    @type syslog
    expression /^(?<logtime>[^ ]) (?<host>HOST\d{4}) (?<facility>[^ ]*) (?<message>[\d\w\s\S\W]*)$/
    time_key logtime
    time_format "%b %d %T"
  </parse>
</source>
```

or

```
<source>
  @type syslog
  port 1514
  tag  scom
  expression  /^\(?<time>[^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<facility>[^ ]*) (?<message>[\d\w\s\S\W]*)$/
  time_format "%b %d %H:%M:%S"
</source>
```

And no one solution is working.

What's wrong?

Comment: Try it like this `^(?<logtime>.*?) (?<host>HOST\d+) (?<facility>\S+) (?<message>.*)` https://regex101.com/r/klNVm6/1 or a little bit more precise `^(?<logtime>[A-Z][a-z]+) \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} (?<host>HOST\d+) (?<facility>\S+) (?<message>.*)` https://regex101.com/r/jSJZHP/1

Comment: ``<source>
  type tail
  path /var/log/foo/bar.log
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/foo-bar.log.pos
  tag foo.bar
  format /^(?<logtime>[A-Z][a-z]+) \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} (?<host>HOST\d+) (?<facility>\S+) (?<message>.*)/
</source>`` looks working, it produces ``logtime Aug
host HOST123
facility daemon:warning
message Expiring: (mcpd_process_query_timer)``